# Proving $x^x$ is strictly less than $(1-x)^{1-x}$ on $(0,\frac{1}{2})$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality, logarithms, exponential-function

I am trying to prove the following:

$x^x < (1-x)^{1-x}$ for $x \in (0,\frac{1}{2})$

(or take logs of both sides to make it nicer if you want)

I can draw pictures to convince myself this is true, but I'm wondering how to structure a formal argument. It feels that the second derivative being strictly decreasing in $x$ should help, but I can't quite piece together an argument.

Any ideas would be gratefully received!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f(x)=(1-x)\ln(1-x)-x\ln{x}.$

Thus, since $$f''(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{1}{x}=\frac{2x-1}{x(1-x)}<0,$$
$$f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=0$$ and 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}f(x)=0,$$ we obtain $$f(x)>0$$ or
$$x^x<(1-x)^{1-x}.$$

Comment: That does it for me!! Think I was just being dumb about the second derivative. Makes sense that if it's negative and we have two zeros, then the function must be positive between those points. Thanks! :)

Comment: Yes, we got that $f$ is a concave function on $\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right).$ You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Well we have $x < 1-x$ on that range so both the base and the exponent of $(1-x)^{1-x}$ are larger than the base and exponent of $x^x$ so we can do this in a few steps by noting $$x^x < (1-x)^x < (1-x)^{1-x}$$ because for positive $x$ and some $c > 0$ we know <s>both c^x and</s> $x^c$ are strictly monotonically increasing.

Edit: I overlooked that $c^x$ is decreasing when $0<c<1$ so the argument fails as pointed out in the comments.

Comment: $c^x$ is decreasing if $c < 1$

Comment: @DarkMalthorp Yeah that is definitely a problem. Thanks for pointing out my error.

Comment: You definitely need to use more than just the fact that $x < 1-x$; it's the fact that they are equidistant from 0 and 1, respectively, that ensures the strict inequality. Essentially, both are coming away from the interval endpoints at the same rate, but in the $(0,\frac{1}{2})$ the slope is that much steeper. I feel like using the curvature (2nd derivative) should help but in what way?